# Go lang "go get" with error "zip file too big" -- reedit my question

Tags: go, module, download

In Ubuntu 16.04, I run "swag init", it running into an error:

*go get github.com/paulxiong/cervical@1b2d2657e8dab3ba41226f02bbc79fac089290c6:downloaded zip file too large*

Since "swag init" works before, so I tried directly download cervical @ commit as some others advised:

*"go get -d github.com/paulxiong/cervical@6b0d61a8caebdca4a158df72962485a7a1d7fe88" but got an error: "module source tree too big"*

Still error. Plus "git clone ssh://gihub.com/paulxiong/cervical" works fine.

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Why do you try to **go** get a Python project? What is unclear with the error message? You asked "what is wrong?", well you where told the answer "module source tree too big" so what is the question? Also: Your OS version is pretty uninteresting but you Go version would be.

Comment: I used "swag init" to generate a rest-api. this command ends up with errors like "go get github.com/paulxiong/cervical@1b2d2657e8dab3ba41226f02bbc79fac089290c6:downloaded zip file too large".  Since "swag init" works fine before, I tried different commits of cervical with go get.

Answer (score 1):

There is a size limit for what `go get` can fetch. See [this issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/40780) for the reasons (one seems to be fear of abuse of proxy servers).

Since this repository is a Python repo, just use `git clone` instead.

Comment: Yes, get clone has no issue. But the issue is in "swag init".

Answer (score 0):

A crude option, if you cannot "break up the modules". I wouldn't recommend this, but I couldn't find another approach

This worked with errors:

```
create zip: module source tree too large
```

and

```
zip file too large
```

To fix this I had to actually change the limits in the go source code, rebuild go, then replace. version 1.19.2 v1.19.2

**First step is changing the download limits** set in `/Users/me/$GOROOT/src/cmd/go/internal/modfetch/codehost/codehost.go`:

```
// Downloaded size limits.
const (
    MaxGoMod   = 16 << 20     // maximum size of go.mod file
    MaxLICENSE = 16 << 20     // maximum size of LICENSE file
    MaxZipFile = 1000 << 20 // maximum size of downloaded zip file (****this was 500****)
)
```

**Second step is changing download limits** in `/Users/me/$GOROOT/src/cmd/vendor/golang.org/x/mod/zip/zip.go`:

```
const (
    // MaxZipFile is the maximum size in bytes of a module zip file. The
    // go command will report an error if either the zip file or its extracted
    // content is larger than this.
    MaxZipFile = 1000 << 20 // (****this was 500****)

    // MaxGoMod is the maximum size in bytes of a go.mod file within a
    // module zip file.
    MaxGoMod = 16 << 20

    // MaxLICENSE is the maximum size in bytes of a LICENSE file within a
    // module zip file.
    MaxLICENSE = 16 << 20
)
```

**Third step is to rebuild go and replace the binary**:

Under `/Users/me/$GOROOT/src`  there should be a file `make.bash`

Run `./make.bash` and it will rebuild the binary

That fixed this for me on the next `go mod tidy`